# MySQL export indices

Tags: sql, mysql, export, indexing, extract

I'm sure it must have been asked before, but I can't find it:

I have a CMS that is under constant development. I have built a number of websites using the CMS, so their are a number of databases in existence.

I want to extract the indices from the development db and apply them to the production dbs. Is there an easy way to extract indices as SQL?

Something along the lines of:

```
create index idx1 on one (lft, rght);
create index idx1 on two (alias);
create index acos_idx3 on three (model, related_id);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is what you want to do? Indexes are usually created on-the-fly, as data is added. They are strongly tied to the data in the table, so even if you could do it, I can't see what use copying index from one DB to another would be.

Comment: It's not about extracting the index data, but rather the index definitions.

For example, `mysqldump --no-data` would export all the statements, including the index statements, I guess.

I have PowerDesigner installed on my computer, so I have other means to retrieve the indices.

Comment: @Mike: see edited question to show example output.

Comment: @pascal: Yes, that would make a lot more sense :-) @Leo: Looks like I misunderstood, sorry!

Comment: @Leo - was ceteras's answer what you needed?  If not, could you clarify what about their answer isn't quite right?  Perhaps he or others will be able to come up with a more appropriate answer!

Comment: @MaasSql: It's close. I have written a php script to extract the indices, but have been sidetracked by a more pressing problem. When I get back to it - hopefully today or tomorrow - I'll post the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract indices from INFORMATION_SCHEMA database, then add them on another database, but it's not quite easy.

To give you an example (code from a stored procedure used for deployment), this adds an unique key if it's not already there:

```
if not exists (select * from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
                where table_schema = 'database_name' 
                and table_name='your_table'
                and constraint_name ='key_name')
then
    alter table your_table add unique key `key_name` ('column_name');
end if;
```

You can basically find whatever you need in INFORMATION_SCHEMA. I believe you can write code to dynamically check for all these indices, but I'm not sure if it's easy for you.

**UPDATE:**

You can also use `show index from database.table`, as you can see at the link provided by MaasSql's answer. Then loop throuth the results and add each index if it's not in the database.

Or you can try this:

```
if not exists (select * from information_schema.STATISTICS
where table_schema = 'database_name' 
and table_name='table_name'
and index_name ='key_name')
then 
...
end if;
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing I'm looking for, but bizarrely not all of the indexes are listed!

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with My SQL a whole lot, but as I remember, the backups were open text DDL statements.  Seems like that would mean that the beginning of each backup would contain all of the tables, then all of the indexes.?

Maybe this command with a bit of table looping will get you want you want: [My SQL 5.0 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html).

Good LUCK!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to move onto something else and this is as far as I got (just before Ceteras published his update!). The problem at the moment is that CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS is invalid, so I need to find another way to do it. Might get back on this at the end of the week.

```
$query="SHOW TABLES";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $idxQ = "SHOW INDEXES FROM {$row[0]} IN $database;";
  $idxR = mysql_query($idxQ);

  while($idxRow = mysql_fetch_object($idxR))
  {
      //basic query: CREATE INDEX indexName ON tableName (columnName);
      $indexName = $idxRow->Key_name;
      if($indexName=='PRIMARY') continue;
      $tableName = $idxRow->Table;
      $columnName = $idxRow->Column_name;
      $idxCreateQ = "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS $indexName ON $tableName ($columnName);";
      echo $idxCreateQ;
  }
```

}